# Android - different rendering behavior between string from list vs new string

Tags: java, android, string, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In my Android program I have many arrays and lists storing a few hundred strings each. I will sometimes get a string from one of these structures and use it to draw text to the screen programmatically (example below).

```
String displayText = titleList[i];
renderText(displayText);
```

Everything renders as expected on my current device. I wanted to support it back to jelly bean (api 16-18) but on my jelly bean device, the strings will sometimes not render to the screen or will only render the first half or will render a few strings but not the rest in a list. Logging the value of these strings passed to the renderer prints as expected. The odd thing is that if I build a new string from the referenced string (example below), it works!

```
String displayText = new String(titleList[i]);
renderText(displayText);
```

I could do this, but it seems like it would be wasteful and might impact performance to build new strings every time I reference one that already exists, especially since it works on newer devices. And Android Studio tells me I'm stupid ("new String is redundant"). I'm also just curious how this is even possible and would like a better way to fix it.

Comment: If it works on one version and not another, the code that would be most relevant would be the code in `renderText()` where you actually interact with Android.

Comment: Maybe you have a race condition.. Are you interacting with the data from another thread?

Comment: @Jack just using "canvas.drawText", nothing fancy

Comment: @HedShafran The strings are loaded from files when the app loads and aren't being modified. And like I said, when I print the strings to console before and after the render, they show up as expected.

Comment: Please post more code... for example, where is the 'i' coming from?

Comment: Your problem is most likely with the canvas since that's really the only thing that would change between apis (not how strings work). See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120042/android-canvas-drawtext-not-working) helps at all. The whole new string thing is weird though.

Comment: @HedShafran Then I think I would have to post my entire project. Going from file to lists to the rendering goes through half the project code. Maybe I need to attempt to make a barebones project with lists of strings that render to screen.

Comment: @Jack See the strange thing is that in one instance of this glitch, when using new string it displayed "My Title" but without using new String it displayed "My Ti" only. It's completely bizarre. And it always cuts at the same part despite when it is accessed and still prints out fine.

Comment: I wonder if you have a race condition between the width of the view and text length, and just putting in `new String` is enough to stop it.

Comment: @Jack But where would the race condition come from? I tried sleeping for 50ms between each time it grabbed a new string instead of creating a new String but that didn't work. And everything else renders on the canvas, just the text has a problem. Even updating the canvas works for other things but the text remains empty.

Comment: Are you reusing the same view or viewholder in a list? It could be saving the width from the last layout and not updating in time for the new text. Can you put a `.post()` and redraw the width after you've set the text? I had a strange issue once where I was putting a rightdrawable on a textview in a list and sometimes it would cut off the text in a similar way you are describing so I had to `post()` the setting of the drawable.

Comment: Based on your questions I found and fixed the problem. I forgot I have a function that added spacing to strings like so: string.replace("", " "); I found that at some point the strings were actually printing blank and tracked it down to this line. So I spent the last hour editing my font to give the spacing I wanted and removing this line. But the mystery still stands. The UI and string replace were both on the main thread so there shouldn't be a race condition. Why would string.replace return an empty string sometimes when passed a list reference but never when passed a new reference?